# How to create a "property viewer" control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create something similar to the Visual Studios Properties viewer:

[image: property viewer]

Is this a TableLayoutPanel, 2 ListBox next to eachother, a SplitContainter or a big bunch of TextBox?

Comment: [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Winforms had [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx). In WPF, it's fairly straightforward to produce something similar.

Comment: Why downvotes? What's wrong with the question? @Downvoters please keep in mind, no body born with the knowledge that this is a `PropertyGrid`. Without knowing the term, OP can't even google! So IMO this is a valid question and doesn't deserve downvotes.

Comment: Also if something does deserve a down vote it is suggested to add a comment stating why.

Comment: @PaulBinder No it isn't (not that I downvoted anyway)

Comment: It literally pops up a suggestion stating to add a comment if you think the post could be improved. Clearly if users are down voting a question they believe the asker could improve how they ask questions. So how is it not suggested?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be a [PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you're interested in wusing WPF instead of Forms, [Xceed has also implemented the PropertyGrid for WPF](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid)